# How to check the CPU and memory usage of an executable?

Tags: windows, monitoring, performance-analysis

I want to see the resources an executable uses when I run it from a command prompt/powershell.

Ideally it would be great to have a tool that does something like this straight from the command prompt:

```
./myexecutable -arg1 -arg2 --trackperformance
cpu usage: 12%
memory usage: 1MB
```

I did read stuff about performance monitor but it doesn't seem to be able to track what I want (CPU usage, memory usage overall for the specific executable that I will run).

Any ideas of a tool or command built into the command line that does this for the Windows OS?

Answer (score 2):

**Process Lasso**

From their site:

> Process Lasso is Windows process automation and optimization software. From tuning algorithms like ProBalance to user-created rules and persistent settings such as CPU affinities and priority classes, Process Lasso gives you complete control over running applications!

[image]

Homepage: https://bitsum.com/

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows**, it *might* help to install the Windows Subsystem for Linux [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about), or install [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) from the Microsoft Sysinternals toolsuite.

On **Linux**, you can use `pidstat` (from the `sysstat` package) to track cpu- and memory usage of specific processes.

- For instance, open an ebook in an ebook reader. (this is a long-running, single-instance process)
- open a terminal window and type `pidstat -p $(pgrep -f .epub) 1`
- scroll the ebook little bit to give the cpu some work to do

I get this output

```
pidstat -p $(pgrep -f .epub) 1 

Linux 4.15.0-66-generic (xx)    11/14/2019  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)  

12:18:10 PM   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest   %wait    %CPU   CPU  Command
12:18:11 PM  1000     36636    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     3  ebook-viewer
12:18:12 PM  1000     36636    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00     3  ebook-viewer
12:18:13 PM  1000     36636    2.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    2.00     1  ebook-viewer
12:18:14 PM  1000     36636    2.00    2.00    0.00    2.00    4.00     3  ebook-viewer
12:18:15 PM  1000     36636   14.00    1.00    0.00    1.00   15.00     3  ebook-viewer
12:18:16 PM  1000     36636   35.00    2.00    0.00    2.00   37.00     0  ebook-viewer
12:18:17 PM  1000     36636    2.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    2.00     0  ebook-viewer
12:18:18 PM  1000     36636    5.00    1.00    0.00    1.00    6.00     3  ebook-viewer
12:18:19 PM  1000     36636    1.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    1.00     0  ebook-viewer

Average:     1000     36636    5.82    0.55    0.00    0.91    6.36     -  ebook-viewer
```

For short-running processes, and for displaying memory consumption, issue this command:

`pidstat -r 1 -e /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/ebook-viewer /home/knb/Dropbox/books/howlinuxworks.epub`

This gives you this output (note %MEM column) :

```
12:29:01 PM   UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ     RSS   %MEM  Command
12:29:02 PM  1000     43888  23400.00      0.00 2220516  151964   0.62  python2.7
12:29:03 PM  1000     43888  12027.00      0.00 2397208  193584   0.78  python2.7
12:29:04 PM  1000     43888   4562.00      0.00 2478048  197148   0.80  python2.7
12:29:05 PM  1000     43888   3808.00      0.00 2496188  211120   0.86  python2.7
12:29:06 PM  1000     43888    186.00      0.00 2496264  212072   0.86  python2.7
12:29:07 PM  1000     43888      0.00      0.00 2496264  211752   0.86  python2.7
12:29:08 PM  1000     43888     16.00      0.00 2496264  211908   0.86  python2.7
12:29:09 PM  1000     43888     29.00      0.00 2496264  211440   0.86  python2.7
```

Comment: Good suggestion but this is for Linux, any tools for windows? I will edit the question to specify windows OS for the question, my bad.

Comment: @theBigCheese88 I've updated my answer with short Windows example

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, Process Monitor is the way to go for something that provides a UI

https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such as session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.